# How to save value from JSON as HTML code, not as a string, in python?

Tags: python, json, scrapy

Got a JSON data from site. Here's the part of it, I'm interested in.

```
...
"content":{  
         "rendered":"<p><img class=\"aligncenter size-full wp-image-91555\" src=\"https:\/\/ebook3000.biz\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/03\/Edge-May-2019.png\" alt=\"Edge - May 2019 \" width=\"226\" height=\"290\" \/><\/p>\n<p>English |PDF|80 MB<\/p>\n<div class=\"box download  \"><div class=\"box-inner-block\"><i class=\"fa tie-shortcode-boxicon\"><\/i>\n\t\t\t Download<\/p>\n<p><a href=\"https:\/\/dropupload.com\/T97\/2019-05-01_Edge.pdf\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">https:\/\/dropupload.com\/T97\/2019-05-01_Edge.pdf<\/a><\/p>\n\n\t\t\t<\/div><\/div>\n",
         "protected":false
      },
      "excerpt":{  
         "rendered":"<p>English |PDF|80 MB<\/p>\n",
         "protected":false
      },
      "author":1...
```

Want to get value from [content][rendered] as HTML code for using it with xpath. Want to get href value of "dropupload" link.

Here's the code in scrapy spider I'm saving this value now:

`content = mag['content']['rendered']`

But it saved as 'str'. How is it possible to get as HTML?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: But HTML can be stored in string, yes. What data type do you need exactly?

Comment: I want to use this html with xpath. And I'm not sure how should I save this value for future processing with xpath expretions. No matter in which format)

Comment: Trying to use .xpath() on saved value - got traceback "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'xpath'"

Comment: basically what the guy wants is normal html code without the escaped chars...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have string with your HTML. Then you can use it in separate selector, like here:

```
from scrapy import Selector
sel = Selector(text=mag['content']['rendered'])
print sel.css('a::attr(href)').get()  # or your css/xpath selector here
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks man! It helps! I already spent for 4 hours trying to figure out how to do it)